# post-hoc test of sm.ancova (non-parametric ancova)

Tags: r, posthoc, ancova

I'm trying to use a non-parametric ancova on my data set.

Currently, I'm using package `sm` for the function `sm.ancova`

However, I'm not sure which post-hoc test I should be using for the data.

Would there be any recommended statistical test or a package?

Comment: Refer `fANCOVA ` package

Comment: fANCOVA doesn't seem to allow hypothesis testing, and also, it does not allow categorical covariates for its semi-parametric ANCOVA (loess.ancova) any other suggestions?

Comment: How about `np.ancova` in `PLRModels`?

Comment: the `np.ancova` from `PLRModels` doesn't seem to include post-hoc also